# Is there a problem with my dataprep during lda analysis?

Tags: r, lda

I am getting an error while trying to run lda on a subset of iris dataset in R. The variable lengths seem to be different and i do not see why?

"Error in table(original = y[test], predicted = pred_class) : 
  all arguments must have the same length"

I have tried splitting the variable using subset, with, filter etc but keep getting the same error

```
iris_or<-with(iris, iris[order(Species),])
head(iris_or)
iris_or<-iris_or[51:150,]


spor = sample(nrow(iris_or), nrow(iris_or)*.75) #sampling without replacement
dtrainor<-iris_or[spor,]
summary(dtrainor)
dtestor<-iris_or[-spor,]
summary(dtestor)


orlda = linDA(dtrainor[,1:4], dtrainor[,5])
summary(orlda)
orlda$functions
```

I am expecting the lda output basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you are removing a factor from your data frame but not dropping the unused factor level, which is interfering with how linDA reads your data frame. Use `droplevels()` before placing you data frame in the linDA function. Below is an approach.

```
  test <- iris[iris$Species != 'setosa',]
  ind <- sample(nrow(test), nrow(test)*.75)
  td <- iris_or[ind,]
  dte<-iris_or[-ind,]

  td <- droplevels(td) # removing unused levels

  ana <- linDA(td[,1:4], td$Species)
  ana

  Linear Discriminant Analysis
  -------------------------------------------
  $functions        discrimination functions
  ....
```